# Why would a Spark job fail without throwing run-time exceptions?

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I'm going through a problem in which my job fails at a particular stage when it invokes a class.

Here's the line

```
val stockDataFilteredRDD: RDD[stockPriceInfo] =
  lineMapToStockPriceInfoObjectRDD
  .map(new stockDataFilter(_).requirementsMet.get)
```

Here's what I see

```
15/10/0916:02:28INFOClient:ApplicationreportfromResourceManager:
applicationidentifier:application_1438798768056_0254
appId:254
clientToAMToken:null
appDiagnostics:
appMasterHost:ip-10-0-142-138.ec2.internal
appQueue:root.add_twitter_user
appMasterRpcPort:0
appStartTime:1444421062565
yarnAppState:RUNNING
distributedFinalState:UNDEFINED
appTrackingUrl:http://myIP.ip

15/10/0916:02:29INFOClient:ApplicationreportfromResourceManager:
applicationidentifier:application_1438798768056_0254
appId:254
clientToAMToken:null
appDiagnostics:
appMasterHost:ip-10-0-142-138.ec2.internal
appQueue:root.add_twitter_user
appMasterRpcPort:0
appStartTime:1444421062565
yarnAppState:FINISHED
distributedFinalState:FAILED
appTrackingUrl:http://myIP.ip
appUser:add_twitter_user
```

The class invoked

```
class stockDataFilter(val s:stockPriceInfo){

val dateDelim="-"
val timeDelim=":"
val dateAndTime=s.dateTime
val splitDateTime=dateAndTime.split("@")
val dateStamp=splitDateTime(0)
val time=splitDateTime(1)
val splitDate=dateStamp.split(dateDelim)
val splitTime=time.split(timeDelim)
val year=splitDate(0);
val month=splitDate(1);
val day=splitDate(2)
val hour=splitTime(0);
val minute=splitTime(1);
val second=splitTime(2)

val openingBell:LocalTime=newLocalTime(9,30)
val closingBell:LocalTime=newLocalTime(16,0)
val currentTime:LocalTime=newLocalTime(hour.toInt,minute.toInt)

//NonTradingSessions
val newYearsDay:Date=newDate(year.toInt-1900,0,1)
val weekends:List[String]=List("Saturday","Sunday")

val date=new Date(year.toInt-1900,month.toInt-1,day.toInt)
val currentDate=new LocalDate(year.toInt-1990,month.toInt-1,day.toInt)

//NewYorkStockExchangeoperatesfrom9:30a.m.to4:00p.m
def isWithinTradingSession:Boolean={
    val isAfterOpen:Boolean=currentTime.isAfter(openingBell)
    val isBeforeClose:Boolean=currentTime.isBefore(closingBell)
    isAfterOpen&&isBeforeClose
}//return Trueifitiswithingtradingtime

def requirementsMet:Option[stockPriceInfo]=isWithinTradingSessionmatch{
   case true=>Some(s)
   case false=>None
 }
}
```

I am able to display(store in HDFS) anything before that, but once I add this line, it fails. I've looked at the logs, there are no obvious issues. There was also no compile-time or run-time exception. I've been stuck on this for days out of options. Your help would be appreciated.. Regards

LOGS:

```
LogType: stderr
LogLength: 6638
Log Contents:
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.2.1-1.cdh5.2.1.p0.12/jars/spark-assembly-1.1.0-cdh5.2.1-hadoop2.5.0-cdh5.2.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.2.1-1.cdh5.2.1.p0.12/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/data01/yarn/nm/usercache/add_twitter_user/filecache/62/twitteryahoofinanceanalytics.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
15/10/10 11:27:24 INFO executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Registered signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
15/10/10 11:27:25 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: yarn,add_twitter_user
15/10/10 11:27:25 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: yarn,add_twitter_user
15/10/10 11:27:25 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(yarn, add_twitter_user); users with modify permissions: Set(yarn, add_twitter_user)
15/10/10 11:27:25 INFO slf4j.Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
15/10/10 11:27:25 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
15/10/10 11:27:26 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://driverPropsFetcher@IP]
15/10/10 11:27:26 INFO Remoting: Remoting now listens on addresses: [akka.tcp://driverPropsFetcher@IP]
15/10/10 11:27:26 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'driverPropsFetcher' on port port.
15/10/10 11:27:26 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: yarn,add_twitter_user
15/10/10 11:27:26 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: yarn,add_twitter_user
15/10/10 11:27:26 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(yarn, add_twitter_user); users with modify permissions: Set(yarn, add_twitter_user)
15/10/10 11:27:26 INFO remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Shutting down remote daemon.
15/10/10 11:27:26 INFO remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remote daemon shut down; proceeding with flushing remote transports.
15/10/10 11:27:26 INFO slf4j.Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
15/10/10 11:27:26 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
15/10/10 11:27:26 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@myIP]
15/10/10 11:27:26 INFO Remoting: Remoting now listens on addresses: [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@myIP]
15/10/10 11:27:26 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkExecutor' on port 54841.
15/10/10 11:27:26 INFO Remoting: Remoting shut down
15/10/10 11:27:26 INFO remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remoting shut down.
15/10/10 11:27:26 INFO executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Connecting to driver: akka.tcp://sparkDriver@IP:port/user/CoarseGrainedScheduler
15/10/10 11:27:26 INFO executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Successfully registered with driver
15/10/10 11:27:26 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: yarn,add_twitter_user
15/10/10 11:27:26 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: yarn,add_twitter_user
15/10/10 11:27:26 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(yarn, add_twitter_user); users with modify permissions: Set(yarn, add_twitter_user)
15/10/10 11:27:26 INFO slf4j.Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
15/10/10 11:27:26 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
15/10/10 11:27:26 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@myIP]
15/10/10 11:27:26 INFO Remoting: Remoting now listens on addresses: [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@myIP]
15/10/10 11:27:26 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkExecutor' on port 36011.
15/10/10 11:27:26 INFO util.AkkaUtils: Connecting to MapOutputTracker: akka.tcp://sparkDriver@IP:PORT/user/MapOutputTracker
15/10/10 11:27:26 INFO util.AkkaUtils: Connecting to BlockManagerMaster: akka.tcp://sparkDriver@IP/user/BlockManagerMaster
15/10/10 11:27:26 INFO storage.DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /data01/yarn/nm/usercache/add_twitter_user/appcache/application_1438798768056_0263/spark-local-20151010112726-839d
15/10/10 11:27:26 INFO storage.DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /data02/yarn/nm/usercache/add_twitter_user/appcache/application_1438798768056_0263/spark-local-20151010112726-4371
15/10/10 11:27:26 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'Connection manager for block manager' on port port.
15/10/10 11:27:26 INFO network.ConnectionManager: Bound socket to port port with id = ConnectionManagerId(myIP,port)
15/10/10 11:27:26 INFO storage.MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 530.3 MB
15/10/10 11:27:26 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
15/10/10 11:27:26 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
15/10/10 11:27:26 INFO util.AkkaUtils: Connecting to HeartbeatReceiver: akka.tcp://sparkDriver@IP/user/HeartbeatReceiver
15/10/10 11:27:27 INFO executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver commanded a shutdown
15/10/10 11:27:27 INFO network.ConnectionManager: Selector thread was interrupted!
15/10/10 11:27:27 INFO network.ConnectionManager: ConnectionManager stopped
15/10/10 11:27:27 INFO storage.MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
15/10/10 11:27:27 INFO storage.BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
15/10/10 11:27:27 INFO remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Shutting down remote daemon.
15/10/10 11:27:27 INFO remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remote daemon shut down; proceeding with flushing remote transports.
15/10/10 11:27:27 INFO remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Shutting down remote daemon.
15/10/10 11:27:27 INFO remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remote daemon shut down; proceeding with flushing remote transports.
15/10/10 11:27:27 INFO Remoting: Remoting shut down
15/10/10 11:27:27 INFO remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remoting shut down.
15/10/10 11:27:27 INFO Remoting: Remoting shut down
15/10/10 11:27:27 INFO remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remoting shut down.

LogType: stdout
LogLength: 0
Log Contents:
```

Comment: That seems to be only the driver's log, and is pretty much useless for debugging. I assume you are using yarn-client mode. Try getting the full logs from Yarn with `yarn logs --aplicationId`

Comment: Hello @DanielL. I already looked at those logs. Every thing there looks ok. I think i'll go ahead and post them.. jic i'm missing something.

Comment: Shouldn't you get one par of stderr and stdout per node? Sorry, don't know how else to help you :-S

Comment: What is `Some(s).get`? As far as I can see this does not match the **return** type ... so does it really compile?

Comment: Thanks  Beryllium.  That's an error on my part.. It was just me trying to see if the Option is the reason why the job fails. But without that, it does compile, and i'm able to build with sbt..